# even spacing of cell and multicell next to each other in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I am generating a pdf (using fpdf) based on user input coming via an html form. The pdf has two columns, the left side has the label of the variable and the right side has the value entered by the user. The problem I am facing is when I have a user input that spans multiple lines. For example, the value of the address can span from 1 line (default address) to up to 4 lines (address input by the user).
Right now I am using multicell to allow user entered address to wrap around the cell, as seen below:

`$fpdf->Cell(65,28,"Address:",1,0);`
`$fpdf->Multicell(125,7,$address,1,'L',false);`

For the "Cell", I have set the height as 28, because I know that the neighboring multicell can span a maximum of 4 lines. But since only the "multicell" expands and not the "cell", in the above code, my output looks like this:
[fpdf output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9NGy.png)

If I change the height and width values of the  "cell" and "multicell" like below:

`$fpdf->Cell(65,7,"Address:",1,0);`
`$fpdf->Multicell(125,7,$address,1,'L',false);`

I get an output like this when the address is more than 1 line:
[fpdf output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlxKU.png)

Is there any solution to ensure that the bot the cells are always the same height and look more even?

Thank you!